# How do you make a custom task to TFS 2015 on premises avaliable

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

I have followed multiple guides and created a VSIX for my build steps. I had an admin upload them and install them to my team project collection. The problem is when I look at the build they aren't available to pull in as tasks. What do I need to do to make them show up?

I have attached the screen shot below of it uploaded. And also a redacted copy of my json config files. I have no idea what is wrong. I also tried using the tfx tool to upload it but it is asking for a personal access token.

I don't believe it is available in 2015. I tried using the workaround but fiddler was giving me a bad header error. If anyone can point out my error it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: TFS Gallery]

vss-extension.json

```
   {
      "manifestVersion": 1,
      "id": "Archive-Source-Task",
      "name": "Archive Source",
      "public": false,
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "publisher": "redacted",
      "description": "Copy the source",
      "targets": [
        {
          "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
      ],
      "categories": [
        "Build and release"
      ],
      "files": [
        {
          "path": "Task"
        },
        {
          "path": "bin"
        }
      ],
      "contributions": [
        {
          "id": "Archive Source",
          "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
          "targets": [
            "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "name": "task"
          }
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        "Build",
        "Release",
        "Management",
        "Utility",
        "Tasks"
      ]
    }
```

task.json

```
    {
  "id": "27203bc5-f3f1-4f80-b2ea-8f62dd4790f1",
  "name": "Archive Source",
  "description": "Copies your source",
  "helpMarkDown": "",
  "category": "Utility",
  "author": "",
  "version": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 0,
    "Patch": 0
  },
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "advanced",
      "displayName": "Advanced",
      "isExpanded": false
    }
  ],
  "instanceNameFormat": "Archive Source",
  "visibility": [
    "Build"
  ],
  "execution": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "target": "$(currentDirectory)\\ArchiveSource.ps1",
      "argumentFormat": "",
      "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the files section in your vss-extension.json file:

```
  "files": [
    {
      "path": "Task"
    },
    {
      "path": "bin"
    }
  ],
```

I suspect that the folder you use to place the task files is named as "Task" instead of "task", so in the contribution section, you should also use "Task" in properties:

```
  "contributions": [
    {
      "id": "Archive Source",
      "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
      "targets": [
        "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "Task"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie, of all the sections, the contributions one still makes the least sense to me. I know what everything else was doing but that one seemed the most like black magic to me. Thanks happy you found it.

Comment: @DoomVroom You can find the instruction for it here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task#step-2-create-the-extension-manifest-file

Answer (score 0):

When we were using TFS 2015 we deployed our task like described in this article: https://blogs.infosupport.com/custom-build-tasks-in-tfs-2015/

The main difference is that you don't need `vss-extension.json` and you deploy it with the power shell script that is provided in this link.

Later when we migrated to TFS 2017 we had to change our build tasks to deploy it like you do.